# Как уменьшить размер при загрузке изображения

Tags: php, ajax, изображения, iframe, загрузка

```
<?php   // work.php
header("Content-Type:text/html;charset=UTF-8"); // Кодирока

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    if ($_FILES['picture']){

            $path = 'images/';
            $tmp_path = 'tmp/';     
            $types = array('image/gif', 'image/png', 'image/jpeg');         
            $size = 6024000;
            $timedate = time().rand(100,999); 

            function resize($file, $type = 2, $rotate = null, $quality = null)
            {
                global $tmp_path;

                // Ограничение по ширине в пикселях
                $max_width_size = 800;
                $max_height_size = 650;     

                // Качество изображения по умолчанию
                if ($quality == null)
                    $quality = 100;

                // Cоздаём исходное изображение на основе исходного файла
                if ($file['type'] == 'image/jpeg')
                    $source = imagecreatefromjpeg($file['tmp_name']);
                elseif ($file['type'] == 'image/png')
                    $source = imagecreatefrompng($file['tmp_name']);
                elseif ($file['type'] == 'image/gif')
                    $source = imagecreatefromgif($file['tmp_name']);
                else
                    return false;

                // Поворачиваем изображение
                if ($rotate != null)
                    $src = imagerotate($source, $rotate, 0);
                else
                    $src = $source;

                // Определяем ширину и высоту изображения
                $w_src = imagesx($src); 
                $h_src = imagesy($src);

                //  Если большое изображение устанавливаем ограничение по ширине.
                if ($type == 2)
                    $w = $max_width_size;

                // Если большое изображение устанавливаем ограничение по высоте.
                if ($type == 2)
                    $h = $max_height_size;


                // Если ширина больше заданной
                if ($h_src > $h)
                {
                    // Вычисление пропорций
                    $ratio = $h_src/$h;
                    $w_dest = @round($w_src/$ratio);
                    $h_dest = @round($h_src/$ratio);

                    // Создаём пустую картинку
                    $dest = @imagecreatetruecolor($w_dest, $h_dest);

                    // Копируем старое изображение в новое с изменением параметров
                    @imagecopyresampled($dest, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $w_dest, $h_dest, $w_src, $h_src);

                    // Вывод картинки и очистка памяти
                    @imagejpeg($dest, $tmp_path . $file['name'], $quality);

                    @imagedestroy($dest);
                    @imagedestroy($src);

                    return $file['name'];

                } else {
                    // Вывод картинки и очистка памяти
                    @imagejpeg($src, $tmp_path . $file['name'], $quality);
                    @imagedestroy($src);

                    return $file['name'];
                }
            }

            $name = resize($_FILES['picture'], $_POST['file_type'], $_POST['file_rotate']);

            // Загрузка файла и вывод сообщения
            if (!@copy($tmp_path . $name, $path . $name)){
                echo '';
            } else {                        
                echo '<script> window.top.work("' . $path . $_FILES['picture']['name'] . '"); </script>';
            }

            unlink($tmp_path . $name);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Текущий пример чем-то не подходит?

Comment: не подходит. Изображение не уменьшается и не загружается. Не понимаю в чем причина.

Comment: Без iframe все хорошо работает. А с iframe не работает.

Comment: Могу порекомендовать `ImageMagick` http://php.net/manual/ru/book.imagick.php

Answer (score 1):

Знакомый скрипт загрузки и сжатия картинки, сам с ним долго морочился, наконец переделал его. Вот что - то вроде этого.

```
class download_image
{


    protected $path;
    protected $tmp_path;
    protected $types;
    protected $size;

// Функция изменения размера
// Изменяет размер изображения в зависимости от type:
//  type = 1 - эскиз
//  type = 2 - большое изображение
//  rotate - поворот на количество градусов (желательно использовать   значение 90, 180, 270)
//  quality - качество изображения (по умолчанию 75%)
public function prepare($file)
{
    //Извлекаем путь к папке сайта
    $path = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'];
    //Обрубаем ипсолняемый файл в строке
    $path = str_replace("index.php", '', $path);
    $path .= "куда грузим";
    $path0 = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];

    function resize($file, $type = 1, $rotate = null, $quality = null){
        global $tmp_path;
        $w ='';

        // Ограничение по ширине в пикселях
        $max_thumb_size = 200;
        $max_size = 600;

        if ($quality == null){
            $quality = 0;
        }

        // Cоздаём исходное изображение на основе исходного файла
        if ($file['type'] == 'image/jpeg'){
            $source = imagecreatefromjpeg($file['tmp_name']);
        }elseif ($file['type'] == 'image/png'){
            $source = imagecreatefrompng($file['tmp_name']);
        }elseif ($file['type'] == 'image/gif'){
            $source = imagecreatefromgif($file['tmp_name']);
        }else{
            return false;
        }

        // Поворачиваем изображение
        if ($rotate != null){
            $src = imagerotate($source, $rotate, 0);
        }else{
            $src = $source;
        }

        $w_src = imagesx($src);
        $h_src = imagesy($src);

        imagepng($src, $path.$name, $quality, PNG_NO_FILTER);
        imagedestroy($src);
         return $file['name'];
    }

    // Массив допустимых значений типа файла
    $types = array('image/jpg', 'image/png', 'image/jpeg');
    // Максимальный размер файла 5 Мб
    $size = 1024*1024*5;

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
            // Проверяем тип файла
            if (!in_array($file['picture']['type'], $types)){
                $err[7] = 'Запрещённый тип файла.';
            }
            if ($file['picture']['size'] > $size){
                $err[8] = 'Максимальный размер файла 5 Мб.';
            }

            $name = resize($file['picture'], $file['picture']['type'],'0');
            $tmp_name = $file["picture"]["tmp_name"];
            $name = $file["picture"]["name"];

            if (!move_uploaded_file( $tmp_name, $path.$name)) {
                $err[9] = 'Не удалось загрузить картинку';
            }
            Переменная $web загружает в бд путь к картинке
            $web = $path.$name;
            $web = str_replace('полный путь к папке ','',$webpath);
    }

    if (count($err) != 0)
    {
        //Выдает ошибку
        return $err;
    }
    else
    {
        //Возвращаем путь
        return $web;
    }
}
}
```

**Если выхотите чтобы ваш сайт работал быстро не грузите в БД саму картинку! Проще и удобнее записать путь к загруженной картинке**

Comment: Ну а это для красоты?  `// Ограничение по ширине в пикселях
        $max_thumb_size = 200;
        $max_size = 600;`