# Как сгенерировать уменьшенную копию изображения с сервера?

Tags: javascript, php

Мне нужно изменить размер изображения при выводе на сайте. В вордпресс например, сразу создаются 20 размеров для 1 изображения, а я ищу универсальный способ который будет отдавать браузеру уменьшенную копию изображения с сервера, то есть чтобы не создавать 20 миниатюр, а генерировать их.

Одна фотография должна выводиться на сайте в нескольких размерах.

Comment: задать в css размеры для img 250x250

Comment: А как вы хотите из прямоугольной картинки сделать квадратную?

Comment: Советчики такие советчики, в стилях прописать ширину, и потом для картинки 250 на 250 грузить исходную мегабайтную картинку 1920 на 1080 и сжимать в браузере.

Comment: Вам бы по хорошему сделать оптимизацию изображения при его загрузке или вручную при первой отдаче.. Если картинки в низком качестве нет, то сервер должен сгенерировать ее и отдать. Либо же, при загрузке картинки на сервер можно уменьшать ее и вес соответственно.

Comment: @MoloF Фотографии оптимизированы, но одна фотография должна выводиться на сайт в нескольких размерах. Как это можно реализовать "сервер должен сгенерировать ее и отдать" направьте меня, я код сам напишу

Comment: @АндрейПовх [resize-image-in-php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14649645) , [Which is the best PHP method to reduce the image size without losing quality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11418594)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как уменьшить размер при загрузке изображения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/504690/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8c%d1%88%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f)

Comment: @АлексейШиманович 
мне нужно изменить размер при выводе на сайте. В вордпрес например, сразу создаются 20 размеров для 1 изображение, а я ищу универсальный способ который будет отдавать браузеру уменьшенную копию изображения с сервера, то есть чтобы не создавать 20 миниатюр, а генерировать их

Comment: @АндрейПовх не пытайтесь на "лету" генерировать изображения, ваш сервер просто упадет от перегруза, если бы это был хороший вариант, никто бы и не стал генерировать по 20 изображений как это делает WordPress.

Comment: @u_mulder, при первой версии вопроса не совсем ясно было что нужно автору.

Comment: Если у вас сильно нагруженный сайт, то никаких "на лету", наоборот у вас будет настроен какой-нибудь Nginx, который будет по-быстрому отдавать закешированные статические картинки. Тут уж что-то одно - или скорость отдачи контента, или экономия места.

Comment: @MoloF ну почему же, можно купить облако на сотни серверов, задеплоить специальный прокси-микровервис обработки картинок и обрабатывать на лету, не забывая кэшировать самые популярные запросы, тот же гугл так делает ;)

Comment: @andreymal идея хорошая, особенно для автора вопроса на 10 с половиной посетителей :D

Comment: @CrazyElf если это небольшое количество картинок то да, но если это обилие изображений, я думаю кэш лопнет. Да и что дешевле, кэш или место на диске?

Comment: Спасибо всем, за объяснение, сделаю как на Wordpress

Comment: @MoloF Хороший кэш умеет хранить в быстрой памяти только то, что очень популярно, а редко используемые элементы вытесняются )  Ну и так вообще скорее процессорных мощностей будет не хватать под лишнюю обработку, чем места под уменьшенные версии картинок, которые и так уже хранятся в любом случае (сами то картинки исходные).

Comment: @u_mulder, а если progressive jpeg совместить с css, браузер всё равно будет тянуть картинку целиком?

Comment: В итоге же получится что браузер будет тянуть все версии картинки чтобы её показать. Это более менее сработает если показывать оригинальные мегабайтные изображения. А чтобы показать маленькую картинку мне кажется с прогрессивным джипегом будет больше возни, чем профита.

Comment: Не пытайтесь изобрести велосипед. Генерация изображений "на лету" действительно довольно сильно нагружает процессор т.к использует математические вычисления. И, если у Вас сайт располагается на хостинге, то скорее всего соответствующие функции в популярных языках программирования хостер отключил. Поэтому лучшим решением все же будет именно предварительная генерация изображений нужных размеров и помещение их в соответствующие папки откуда Вы их и будете показывать пользователям. Именно так и делают практически все популярные фото-хостинги.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class Picture {

    private $image_file;

    public $image;
    public $image_type;
    public $image_width;
    public $image_height;
    public function __construct($image_file) {
        $this->image_file=$image_file;
        $image_info = getimagesize($this->image_file);
        $this->image_width = $image_info[0];
        $this->image_height = $image_info[1];
        switch($image_info[2]) {
            case 1: $this->image_type = 'gif'; break;//1: IMAGETYPE_GIF
            case 2: $this->image_type = 'jpeg'; break;//2: IMAGETYPE_JPEG
            case 3: $this->image_type = 'png'; break;//3: IMAGETYPE_PNG
            case 4: $this->image_type = 'swf'; break;//4: IMAGETYPE_SWF
            case 5: $this->image_type = 'psd'; break;//5: IMAGETYPE_PSD
            case 6: $this->image_type = 'bmp'; break;//6: IMAGETYPE_BMP
            case 7: $this->image_type = 'tiffi'; break;//7: IMAGETYPE_TIFF_II (порядок байт intel)
            case 8: $this->image_type = 'tiffm'; break;//8: IMAGETYPE_TIFF_MM (порядок байт motorola)
            case 9: $this->image_type = 'jpc'; break;//9: IMAGETYPE_JPC
            case 10: $this->image_type = 'jp2'; break;//10: IMAGETYPE_JP2
            case 11: $this->image_type = 'jpx'; break;//11: IMAGETYPE_JPX
            case 12: $this->image_type = 'jb2'; break;//12: IMAGETYPE_JB2
            case 13: $this->image_type = 'swc'; break;//13: IMAGETYPE_SWC
            case 14: $this->image_type = 'iff'; break;//14: IMAGETYPE_IFF
            case 15: $this->image_type = 'wbmp'; break;//15: IMAGETYPE_WBMP
            case 16: $this->image_type = 'xbm'; break;//16: IMAGETYPE_XBM
            case 17: $this->image_type = 'ico'; break;//17: IMAGETYPE_ICO
            default: $this->image_type = ''; break;
        }
        $this->fotoimage();
    }

    public function imagesave($image_type='jpeg', $image_file=NULL, $image_compress=100, $image_permiss='') {
        if($image_file==NULL) {
            switch($this->image_type) {
                case 'gif': header("Content-type: image/gif"); break;
                case 'jpeg': header("Content-type: image/jpeg"); break;
                case 'png': header("Content-type: image/png"); break;
            }
        }
        switch($this->image_type) {
            case 'gif': imagegif($this->image, $image_file); break;
            case 'jpeg': imagejpeg($this->image, $image_file, $image_compress); break;
            case 'png': imagepng($this->image, $image_file); break;
        }
        if($image_permiss != '') {
            chmod($image_file, $image_permiss);
        }
    }

    public function imageout() {
        imagedestroy($this->image);
    }
    public function imageresize($new_w, $new_h) {
        $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($new_w, $new_h);
        imageAlphaBlending($new_image, false);
        imageSaveAlpha($new_image, true);
        imagecopyresampled($new_image, $this->image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_w, $new_h, $this->image_width, $this->image_height);
        $this->image_width = $new_w;
        $this->image_height = $new_h;
        $this->image = $new_image;
    }
}
```

```
$new_image = new Picture($filepath);
$new_image->imageresize($new_width, $new_height);
$new_image->imagesave($new_image->image_type, $newfilepath, 80);
$new_image->imageout();
```

Comment: Если чего-то нехватает - пиши, помогу

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]